# Xpath is not giving result scrapy python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, namespaces

I am using xpath to retrieve a PDF link

```
response.xpath('//a[@id="jr-pdf-sw"]/@href')
```

link where I am using this xpath -> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7064742/

My response looks like this:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" class="jr-col-auto js jr js flexbox no-touch draganddrop csscolumns csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions boxflex jr-fs-12 no-animate">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
```

My Xpath resides inside body tag.

Can anyone tell why this xpath is not working? Is it because of namespace?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where does this XPath comes from ? It returns nothing. Maybe you should post the code inside the response body (just the relevant part).

Answer (score 0):

Working XPaths. Classic form :

```
//div[@class="format-menu"]//a[contains(.,"PDF")]/@href
```

If namespace is the problem :

```
//*[local-name(.)='div'][@class='format-menu']//*[local-name(.)='a'][contains(.,'PDF')]/@href
```